# VBS Running Macro Enabled Workbook Error 800A9C68

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I'm having a small issue with a VBS script I pieced together from the internet.

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook


Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("LOCATION", 0, True)


xlapp.Visible = True

xlApp.Run "RefreshAdj"

xlBook.Close False
set xlBook = Nothing

xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

It will run off task scheduler but it always gives this error.

```
Line: 11
Char: 1
Error: Unknown runtime Error
Code: 800A9C68
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime Error
```

Its not that big of a deal, but slightly annoying because it will not run the next day until someone clears the dialog box for this error.

Comment: That seems to be an error from the macro you're calling.

Comment: What's on line 11?  And have you tried adding error handling in your vbscript?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Its weird because if I run the macro alone it runs fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams I haven't tried error handling. Its a very messy Recorded macro pieced together. Would you happen to know some resources or ways to add error handling to a recorded macro.

Comment: Since it's a vbscript error I  meant add error handling in your vbscript.  Again - what's on line 11 of your vbscript?

Comment: Did you try `xlApp.Run "file.xlsx!RefreshAdj"`?

Comment: @TimWilliams On line 11 
(xlApp.Run "RefreshAdj")

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I've tried that but that doesn't even run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had the same problem in a script where I updated the data in a sheet, saved the file with a different name and then did

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

I think the problem is that by saving the file with a different name somehow Excel gets confused as to what the ActiveWorkbook is. I had the same error with ThisWorkbook.

Answer (score 0):

My macro is closing the Excel as well with `Activeworkbook.Close`
and VBScript is also closing the Excel application which is not open, thus gives me error: `objExcel.Application.Quit`.
So I removed `ActiveWorkbook.Close` from the macro and now it works fine.